# Convert Multiple Celsius Values to Fahrenheit in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, temperature

I have a text file that has multiple Celsius temperature values that need to be converted to Fahrenheit.

**Text File:**

```
32 28 26 27 28 28 29 27 28 28 30 31 31 30
```

I had initially thought of `awk '{print ${1..14}' text_file` to separate out each value before performing the conversion but, that didn't seem very efficient...

Answer (score 4):

Iterate over all the fields. Do calculation. Assign the result back to the corresponding variables.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=$i*1.8+32}}1' file
```

Formula for celcius to Fahrenheit conversion is,

```
32 deg cel * 1.8 + 32
```

Example:

```
$ echo '32 28 26 27 28 28 29 27 28 28 30 31 31 30' | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=$i*1.8+32}}1'
89.6 82.4 78.8 80.6 82.4 82.4 84.2 80.6 82.4 82.4 86 87.8 87.8 86
```

or

```
awk -v RS=" " '{printf("%.1f ",$1*1.8+32)}'
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Is there a way to ensure that the converted values all have one decimal place, even if they come out to a whole number? e.g. "77.0" instead of just "77."

Comment: think it's rounded to 1 dec place if the dot is not followed by 0.

Comment: Aaron, to control the format of the numbers that get printed, use the `printf()` function.  You could also use `RS`.  For example, `awk -v RS=" " '{printf("%.1f ",$1*1.8+32)}'`

Comment: @AvinashRaj great answer, but it's worth noting for future readers that changing the content of fields collapses whitespace, so while the fields will be correct, the printed line will lose any formatting.